# Negative mass of sound waves?

Tags: general-relativity, acoustics

I have just discovered multitudes of pop science articles promoting a recent arxiv paper, "The mass of sound"[https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.08771 ], which claims that sound waves have negative gravitational mass. Is this a legitimate result? What is the essential argument?

I would normally just read the paper myself, but I am too sick to do so, and thought that an independent assessment by actual physicists might be a public service, given the press coverage.

Comment: Given it is based in part on a Physical Review B paper by the same authors, there has been independent assessment by 'actual physicists'. What, exactly, are you looking for?

Comment: Ironically, I see that the Phys Rev B paper is one that I have intended to read for a long time... In any case: the way that things are reported, does not always correspond to the actual content. Example: https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201707/disperse.cfm

Comment: Yeah, I generally skip the pop science reporting.